# Polarity switching circuit

Tags: mosfet, h-bridge, mosfet-driver

[image]I have a variable resistor as a load that want the current to remain constant by changing the voltage, This circuit also has polarity switching (like H-bridge). Each time the circuit is turned on, user set new  current and Auto transformer that Rotates by ac motor set voltage To keep the current constant. V=0-20v, I= 20-200A!, I found IRF1404 and parallel them (for H-bridge). if there is better circuit please help me!

Comment: Please show your present circuit.

Comment: The output voltage is AC or DC when i see 50Hz?

Comment: @Andyaka please, but the power supply is about 20v not 300v

Comment: @MichalPodmanický DC I'm sorry